# Python as non admin?

Tags: python, windows, administrator

Im trying to package Anaconda with Tensorflow and Keras on Windows 10 for a class in our labs environment which the labs computers do not have administrator access nor do the students for security reasons. 
Problem few lines of code to test to see if the installation is working correctly only work when you launch python as administrator:

```
>>> import keras
c:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 ==
np.dtype(float).type`.
from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Using TensorFlow backend.
```

when running as non admin account:

```
>>> import keras
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
from . import multiarray
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_multiarray)
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
```

`File "c:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils`

`File "c:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import np_utils
  File "c:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\np_utils.py", line 6, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "c:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "c:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "c:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "c:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "c:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try git clean -xdf` `(removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.`

`Original error was: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_multiarray)`